# display an image from a directory that is referenced by a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am trying to create a page where people can upload a picture for everyone to view.

I am trying to store the pictures in a directory and reference the file name via a MySQL table.

The uploading I have managed to sort, it stores the file where I want and adds the file name to the table.

It's viewing the image I am having trouble with. The page just shows a blank space where the pic should be but displays the rest of the info from the table correctly, i.e. who uploaded it and when.

Here is my code:

```
$myObject = new convertToAgo;
//var for gallery output
$returnstr = "";

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures ORDER BY creation_date DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$username = $row["creator_name"];
$date = $row["creation_date"];
$file = $row["file_name"];
$convertedTime = ($myObject -> convert_datetime($date));
$whenAdded = ($myObject -> makeAgo($convertedTime));
$picture = "pictures/$file";

$returnstr .='<img src =\"$picture\" width="400px" height="400px" border="1px"     />
<div class="response_top_div">Added by:&nbsp; ' . $username . ' &nbsp; | &nbsp; ' .     $whenAdded . ' </div>                           <br/><br/><br/>';

}
```

Comment: Check the HTML you're generating. Does the images's `src` point to the right directory? Is the image named correctly?

Comment: did you mean /pictures/ instead?

Comment: All the answers below should fix the problem. Some address the problem more directly than others. Change the quotes to double around the HTML  string, or play with the string concatenation a bit. I personally prefer keeping variables out of my strings as it is easier to read. But yeah, the problem was so blatantly obvious for everyone that you've got 4 answers. Wish I had 4 answers for some of my questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to reference variables within strings. Try this:

```
$myObject = new convertToAgo;

$returnstr = "";

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures ORDER BY creation_date DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $username = $row["creator_name"];
    $date = $row["creation_date"];
    $file = $row["file_name"];
    $convertedTime = ($myObject -> convert_datetime($date));
    $whenAdded = ($myObject -> makeAgo($convertedTime));
    $picture = "pictures/" . $file;

    $returnstr .= '<img src ="' . $picture . '" width="400px" height="400px" border="1px"/>
<div class="response_top_div">Added by:&nbsp; ' . $username . ' &nbsp; | &nbsp; ' .     $whenAdded . ' </div>                           <br/><br/><br/>';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this

```
$picture = "pictures/".$file;

$returnstr .='<img src ="'.$picture.'"
```

or better

```
$returnstr .='<img src ="pictures/'.$file.'"
```

Comment: -1: this does absolutely NOTHING. all you've done is rearrange the furniture a bit. `"$foo = "bar$baz";` and `$foo = "bar" . $baz` are functionally identical in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If the `$returnstr` variable you have is accurate, then you are actually only adding the **string** `$picture` into the src.  You need to concat in the variable:

```
$returnstr .='<img src ="'.$picture.'" width="400px" height="400px" border="1px"     />' ...
```

Comment: You also have to fix the $picture var or it will also only add a string

Comment: although the way he created the `$picture` variable was dirty, it should work because he's using quotation marks, not single quotes - I just believe the syntax highlighting here isn't smart enough.

Answer (score 0):

only double qoutes can accept php variable so change the begining qoutes to double like.

```
$returnstr = "<img src='$you_variable' rel='test_image' />";
```

Hope this works.